# Batch Update Android alarm ringtone?

Tags: audio, alarm

I have a bunch of alarms on my Android phone and I want to change their current ringtone to a new one. The new ringtone is in MP3 format and is located in the sdcard. Is there any way to change them all at once, rather than opening the alarms one by one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. As far as I know, you will have to change them all manually.

You may want to try out other alarm clock apps, though. I use [Alarm Clock Extreme](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alarmclock.xtreme.free) (free & paid), and while I can't batch update in that either, I can set defaults for every option for new alarms.

If you really want a bunch of alarms to have one ringtone that can be updated later, you could use [Llama](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kebab.Llama). One of the features in that app is that you can set a ringtone to a profile (called a LlamaTone). Then when you create an alarm, you tell it to use the Llama ringtone; Llama registers as an option for ringtone selection. In the future, you only change the Llama ringtone, and all the alarms will be updated. Basically, you are creating an alias or shortcut.

---

**Edit** Yes, you can! If you have root, that is. The main alarm clock app keeps all of its alarms in a SQLite database. You can run a sql query to update them in one go.

First, create a new alarm with the ringtone you want ALL other alarms to use. Then run the commands below (in bold). Modify the alert to be the same as the alert you wish to use.

**`sqlite3 /data/data/com.android.deskclock/databases/alarms.db`**

`sqlite>`**`.headers ON`**

`sqlite>`**`select * from alarms;`**

```
_id|hour|minutes|daysofweek|alarmtime|enabled|vibrate|message|alert|intent|no_dialog
 1|15|5|0|0|1|1||content://media/external/audio/media/27||0
 2|15|12|0|0|1|1||content://media/internal/audio/media/58||0
```

`sqlite>`**`update alarms set alert="content://media/internal/audio/media/58";`**

`sqlite>`**`select * from alarms;`**

```
_id|hour|minutes|daysofweek|alarmtime|enabled|vibrate|message|alert|intent|no_dialog
1|15|5|0|0|1|1||content://media/internal/audio/media/58||0
2|15|12|0|0|1|1||content://media/internal/audio/media/58||0
```

Comment: the built in alarm clock has a default for new alarms, at least on ICS and later it does, it's in the settings menu in the app.

Comment: I have about at least 70 alarms in my phone. Today one of my friend tried to prank me by changing all these alarms ringtone to a new scary one. She must have been way too bored to do so. Anyway thank you very much for your answer, now I'm going to change it back to the original ringtone.

Comment: Your pain of editing 70 alarms moved me to find a better solution. Hopefully you have root (and hopefully you see the solution before you have finished all 70 alarms!).

Comment: It's just brilliant, thanks a million! I have done like you said and everything went back to normal now. More than 100 alarms and the query took place in a blink of eye!